# What Twitter API call could i use to return users with a certain range of followers e.g.<10k?

Tags: api, web-applications, twitter

I would like to return a list of users who have the range of twitter followers specified in a request. For example, I would like to return users who have more than 5K followers but less than 20k. How could i possibly do this, if at all?

Comment: list of followers of current user or list of users, who have, for example, not bigger, that 5k (or 10k as you say) followers?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Remember, the type of answer you get depends on the type of question you ask.

Comment: What else is missing @BhavikShah?

@loldop, i am going for the latter... a list of users, regardless of current users, who have the number specified

Answer (score 1):

There is no Twitter API call that will do this. You can request users by id or screen name, but not by the number of followers they have.